# como puedo crear un hipervínculo de un resultado de una consulta traída en formato json

Tags: javascript, php, html5, json

```
            /*=============================================
            TRAEMOS LAS ACCIONES
            =============================================*/

            if (isset($_GET["perfilOculto"]) && $_GET["perfilOculto"] == "Especial") {

                $botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarSistema' idSistema='" . $sistemas[$i]["id"] . "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarSistemas'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button></div>";
            } else {

                $botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarSistema' idSistema='" . $sistemas[$i]["id"] . "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarSistemas'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarSistema' idSistema='" . $sistemas[$i]["id"] . "' codigoSistema='" . $sistemas[$i]["codigoSistema"] . "' imagen='" . $sistemas[$i]["imagen"] . "'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";
            }


            $datosJson .= '[
                  "' . ($i + 1) . '",
                  "' . $imagen . '",
                  "' . $sistemas[$i]["nombreSistema"] . '",
                  "' . $sistemas[$i]["codigoSistema"] . '",
                  "' . $categorias["categoria"] . '",
                  "' . $sistemas[$i]["observacion"] . '",
                  "' . $sistemas[$i]["estatus"] . '",
                  "' . $sistemas[$i]["fechaRegistro"] . '",
                  "' . $botones . '"
                ],';
        }

        $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

        $datosJson .=   ']

         }';

        echo $datosJson;
```

Necesito mostrar nombre del sistema como un hipervínculo para cuando se muestre en mi datatable pueda redireccionar al hacer clic en él, y así poder llevarme a otra vista donde me muestre todos los sub sistemas asociados a este sistema.

En el item que dice descripcion esta reflejado lo que me trajo devolvió la consulta en formato JSON como hago para colocar un vinculo a ese item?

[image: captura1]

Comment: no se como resolver este porblema que tengo soy algo nuevo en esta materia y estoy poco a poco indagando aprendiendo sobre la marcha, por favor quien pueda ayudarme agradecido estare

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con SQL, por esa razón estoy quitando la etiqueta.

Comment: jachguate, saludos como me podrian ayudar con este problema o mala interpretacion que tengo no se como resolver

Comment: Desde PHP estás enviando código HTML para armar la tabla, bien puedes crear el enlace, de la misma forma en que generas los botones.

Comment: Json y html son formatos distintos; mandar uno dentro de otro no es muy limpio (ya sea json en html ó html en json), y es complicarse innecesariamente. Elige uno u otro y haz el resto en javascript.

Comment: Saludos, Sal como sería una manera correcta de aplicar lo que me dices por favor

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacerlo similar al div del botón

Tienes esta linea con la descripción

```
"' . $sistemas[$i]["nombreSistema"] . '",
```

Debería ir así

```
"<a href='aqui_tu_url'>" . $sistemas[$i]["nombreSistema"] . "</a>",
```

Comment: Agradecidos por su colaboración, MR Dev muchas gracias voy a colocarlo en práctica para ver cómo resulta